# Django ManyToMany field related to itself in DRF

Tags: angularjs, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, manytomanyfield

I have a Django Rest Framework and added the model Groups that I'm trying to relate back to itself, in a ManyToMany field called related_groups. The model changes and the makemigrations script created a new table called group_related_groups (Group was a previously implemented model, with new fields added for relationships).

The new model looks like this:

```
class Group(models.Model):
"""
Model definition of a Group. Groups are a collection of users (i.e.
Contacts) that share access to a collection of objects (e.g. Shipments).
"""
group_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
group_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
owner_id = models.ForeignKey('Owner', related_name='groups')
category = models.CharField(max_length=30)
related_groups = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank='true')
```

What I'm wanting to achieve is the related groups column holds the PKs of associated groups. For example, multiple groups of Students could belong to a single group of Counselors, where the Group model is the establishing factor for all Users. Like:

```
| id | group_name | owner_id | category  |
------------------------------------------
| 1  | students1  | 10       | student   |
| 2  | counselors | 10       | counselor |
| 3  | students2  | 10       | student   |
....
| 7  | students3  | 10       | student   |
```

and on the group_related_groups table:

```
| id | from_group_id | to_group_id |
------------------------------------
| 1  | 1             | 2           |
| 2  | 1             | 3           |
| 3  | 1             | 7           |
| 4  | 2             | 1           |
| 5  | 2             | 3           |
| 6  | 2             | 7           |
| 7  | 3             | 1           |
| 8  | 3             | 2           |
| 9  | 3             | 7           |
| 10 | 7             | 1           |
| 11 | 7             | 2           |
| 12 | 7             | 3           |
....................................
```

Is it possible to create a new group and associate it to existing groups at the same time? The new table created by adding the related_groups field is just a relationship table, right? But it'd require a primary key from the new group to create the association... so, a race condition.

Is there a more accepted pattern for relating a model's members to itself?

Edit: added Django Rest Framework as requirement

Comment: Why is it a race condition? Like you say, it's just a relationship table. You need to save the Group, then you can assign the related_groups.

Comment: Right, but I can't create a new group with associations already built in this way... I'd like the user to be able to pre-associate new groups to existing groups in some cases.

Comment: The user doesn't need to know you're saving the group before adding the associations. The form they interact with can have fields to assign the related groups, and then in the view you just create the group, save, then process the related groups they provided...